# How to put the f-statistics and relevant p values for each model in a multivariate multiple regression into a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics

I'm running a model with 5 predictor variables and roughly 70 response variables.  I want to be able to easily look at the f-statistics and p-values for each model. All of the existing answers to this sort of question seem to deal with either univariate regressions or regressions that don't have so many response variables that you can't view all of the output in the Console window. `Glance()` in the `broom` package returns the following error:

```
Error in glance.mlm(df) : 
  glance does not support multiple responses
```

There appears to be no way to work around this.  I am also using R studio so using `summary` returns so many results than I can't view them all in the Console window.  Calling any of the columns listed in summary (`summary(df)$r.squared` for example) returns null.  Does anyone have any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: @Can you post a small example ?

Comment: At a bare minimum you should tell us the type of model you are using (package and function). Though of course even then the question might not be answerable without a **minimal** reproducible example. 2 simulated predictors and 2 responses should be plenty to demonstrate the issue.